# Download third party source code in Play Framework project through IntelliJ

Tags: maven-3, playframework-2.0

See attachement, how can I make IntelliJ download the source code from Maven in a Play Project? I know Play 2.0 uses sbt, but as I have understood sbt also uses the Maven repository infrastructure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to create IntelliJ IDEA project with sources attached?

If that's the case then you can run

```
idea with-sources
```

command to make play console generate all the files required for IDEA and then open generated project. Quite possible that latest trunk of play 2.0 is required for that.

Answer (score 0):

Since play 2.0.1 please note that it's

```
idea sources
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Play 2.2 there are two ways
If you are in the play console, I.e you have run "play" in your play project you use

`idea with-sources=yes`

If you have not launched the play console it is then

```
play idea sources
```

obviously you can substitute idea for eclipse if you are using eclipse ide